# Calculate minimum horizontal distance to avoid overlap when rotating adjacent rectangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rectangles

I have two equally sized rectangles $(2$m $\times$ $1$m$)$ adjacent to each other. When both rectangles are rotated around their centre point, they can overlap, for example at $50$ degrees:

[image: Adjacent rectangles rotated]

Knowing only the dimensions of the rectangles and the angle of rotation, is it possible to determine the minimum horizontal distance, **$X$**, the blue rectangle needs to move to avoid overlap?

I've tried making triangles for basic trigonometry using the centre points (green circles) and creating normals but can't seem to figure out a correct method if it is even possible.

[image: Rectangle dimensions]

Comment: Trying to understand. When there is no gap before rotation there will always be an overlap later.  You want the starting gap width so that they just touch when both rotate  by $ 50^{\circ}$.. right? If so, $ X= \sec 40^{\circ}$ for horizontal center distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are rotating a rectangle in XY plane around its center point, the distance to the four corners (half of the diagonal) will be the radius of the circle as the four corners will always be on the circumference of the circle. If you do not want these rectangles to overlap, you must make sure that the circles drawn do not intersect each other. The minimum distance between them will be when the circles are just touching each other.

Say, the length of the rectangles is a and width is b.

Radius of both circles will be, $r  = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$

The horizontal distance between them in the initial position you have shown will be,

$d = 2r - b = \sqrt {a^2+b^2} - b$

**EDIT:** to include min. distance at individual points as requested -

$d_{\theta} = 2r|sin(\theta+\alpha)|-b$

where $\theta$ is the angle of rotation from the vertical axis.
$\alpha$ is the angle between the long axis and the diagonal of the rectangle,
$r sin \alpha = \frac{b}{2}$; $r cos \alpha = \frac{a}{2}$.

So when they are vertical as in the first diagram of yours, $\theta = 0$.
That means, $d_0 = 0$.

When you rotate by $(90^0-\alpha)$ from vertical position, the distance between them has to be maximum and that is what is given in my solution above.

When they are horizontal ($\theta = 90^0$), distance between them is
$d_{\frac{\pi}{2}} = 2r|sin(90^0+\alpha)| - b = 2rcos \alpha - b = a - b$.

You can also come up with it for rectangles of different dimensions on the same line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I assumed the rotational angle would play a bigger role. The expression you gave results in a horizontal distance that avoids overlaps but not the **minimum** horizontal distance. Taking the 2 rectangles in the first image, the minimum distance is 0 m with no rotation. But if both of those were rotated at 90 degrees, the minimum distance would be 1 m. So I would assume the minimum distance between 0 and 90 degrees would vary with each rotation?

Comment: The distance given by me is the min horizontal distance that would avoid overlap at every point in rotation. Yes at individual points it can be less than this. The equation of the circle can be written as $rsin \theta$ and $rcos \theta$. This can help you in writing min distance at a given point in form of $\theta$. Let me know if you can try writing it. I can edit the response otherwise to write that too.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If you can edit your post to include an expression which takes into account the angle, I would greatly appreciate it as math is unfortunately not one of my strong suits.

Comment: OK. Added further details.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Just to confirm for the 50 degree example, the equation is: $d_{\theta} = 2r|sin(50) +cos(45)|-b$ ?

Comment: My mistake. $d_{\theta} = 2r|sin50 cos45 + cos50 sin45 )|-b$

Comment: Here, $Sin \alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$ and $Cos \alpha = \frac{2}{\sqrt 5}$. Use formula $Sin(A+B) = Sin A Cos B + Cos A Sin B$ to find d. $2r = \sqrt 5$ so it simplifies to $(2.Sin 50^0 + Cos 50^0) - 1$. This is the initial horizontal distance that will avoid overlap at $50^0$ rotation from the vertical position.